# Can I suspend and then resume a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I would like to suspend a Docker container and resume later. How can this be done?
By suspending I mean that it should save the state of ongoing process (e.g. video encoding) and then resume it back at any time.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As of [Version 0.12.0](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0120-2014-06-05), Docker supports `PAUSE` and `UNPAUSE` commands to pause and resume containers using cgroup freezer.

Comment: When you freeze a container, does that mean it can no longer accept any requests? What happens when you send a request to it? Does it queued? Dropped?

Comment: @David Gageot: is there a possibility to clone paused docker containers?

Comment: @noisy Not that I know of. Nearest solution is to use CRIU http://criu.org/Docker

Comment: It doesn't appear that this works on Windows containers, only Hyper-V containers. `Error response from daemon: Cannot pause container f8c3.........: Windows: Containers cannot be paused`

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK right now it can't be done with pure docker but lxc supports that. I've play around little bit with docker and confirmed that this can be done with 
`lxc-freeze -n <containtr.id>` 
and to resume operations 
`lxc-unfreeze -n <container.id>` 
But in v0.2.0 docker ps gives you only shorten containter id even with -notrunc and lxc-ls output is empty on my system (strange, need to read more about it, as docker uses plain lxc-start with params so lxc-ps should print this). I found full container id with `lxc-ps`. It would be nice to add docker freeze command. Maybe it's time for me to learn some go :)

Comment: You can use `docker inspect $container` to get the long id.

Comment: I added full container id when -notrunc is used and change is already in docker git master branch. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have found, that from version 0.9, LXC is no longer default driver for docker (https://blog.docker.com/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/). However there is a possibility to use lxc. To do that, you have to kill docker daemon, and rerun it using a switch `docker -d -e lxc`

Answer (score 6):

The commands:

```
$ docker pause <containerName>
$ docker unpause <containerName>
```

Here's a demo of them in action:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recent [deck on the recent experimental integration of Checkpoint/Restore In Userspace (CRIU) + Docker](https://speakerdeck.com/saied/experimental-docker-checkpoint-and-restore-with-criu).

Answer (score 1):

Docker has just released an (as yet) undocumented volumes and data storage feature set. tl;dr if you use the `-v` commandline option you can specify a path to map outside of the container to a special docker path (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/{FULL_ID}`) where FULL_ID can be found by `docker inspect container_id`. An example is `docker run -d -v /data danielvf/myapp:1.0 runapp` which would externalize the `/data` directory into a docker volume.

https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/111

Roadmap for this feature: (doesn't yet document it's existence):
https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/wiki/Volumes-&-persistent-data-storage