# How can I clear the container related to (kubernetes)k8s?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, kubectl

After I tried to install Clara Deploy SDK, some k8s containers appeared. Now I want to delete these containers but they keep showing up. How can i do this?

I have try to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073721/how-do-i-delete-all-these-kubernetes-k8s-containers), but not work.

container list:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listed containers are core components of Kubernetes cluster. Removing those will completely destroy your cluster.
**You have been warned**

---

Do not use `docker ps` to view Kubernetes resources. Use `kubectl` tool e.g.

```
kubectl get pods
```

to view pods, or

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}"
```

to view names of running containers (pods and containers are not the same thing in Kubernetes).

---

There are clear [instructions on how to uninstall Clara](https://docs.nvidia.com/clara/deploy_ea/0.7.4/ClaraUninstallation.html). You should follow these.
Also official documentation dissuade manual removal of Clara Deploye components:

```
We do not recommend manually deleting Clara Deploy components; the uninstall_prereq.sh script will delete all necessary binaries and stop all Clara Deploy containers.
```

However, if for some reason, you still want to remove mentioned containers read on.

---

As far as I am aware, Clara Deploy SDK default installation uses `helm` to deploy K8s resources. So you can use `helm` to remove containers permanently.

to list installed helm charts:

```
helm list
```

the following helm charts should be returned: <sup>[[source](https://docs.nvidia.com/clara/deploy_ea/0.7.4/ClaraInstallation.html#verify-installation)]</sup>

- clara
- clara-dicom-adapter
- clara-monitor-server
- clara-render-server
- clara-console

to uninstall charts

```
helm uninstall <chart-name>
```